# How do I change this php popup to a link?

Tags: php

I'm looking to change this bit of code to a link instead of having it appear as a small popup window. How would I change it to link to a page of "http://example.com/register" instead of having the registration window drop down?

```
<div class="login-wrapper">
    <a id="sticky-login" class="info-bottom icon-login sticky-button" title="<?php _e('Login',IT_TEXTDOMAIN); ?>"></a>
    <div class="sticky-form" id="sticky-login-form">
        <div class="loading">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <?php echo it_login_form(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems too easy so I'm probably missing something.

You'd add an `href` attribute to the `<a>` tag, and if javascript is creating the popup, remove either the `id` attribute from the `<a>` tag or the class to which the javascript is linked.

```
<a class="info-bottom icon-login sticky-button" title="<?php _e('Login',IT_TEXTDOMAIN); ?>" href="http://example.com/register"></a>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had the href in the wrong spot and I didn't remove the id attribute was what my problem was.

Thank you so much!